# shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation not being called iphone

Tags: iphone

So i'm trying to make some view rotate but the method is not even called and i'm so frustrated. Here is the method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

I also tried:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) ||
            (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}
```

My info.plist looks like this:

[image]

What i'm i missing ? I've looked at all the answers i found here in SO but still the problem remains.

Comment: we need more info. Where are you putting this method. What kind of navigation heirarchy are you using (tab bar?), also in the plist I would add the portrait value, as well as try the Supported interface orientations (iPhone) property instead of the one you currently use (if its still an option in the drop down? I might be remembering that from an old build)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you need specify also portrait orientation as supported in your info.plist.
(Actually it is possible that also removing those orientation keys entirely will do).

By the way: which kind of app are you building? do you use a tab bar or navigation controller (they have specific restrictions for orientation change)?

EDIT:

for a tab bar controller, it is required that all controllers managed by it support a given orientation for autorotation to work.

Comment: +1: he definitely needs to add the portrait orientation to the plist, and also might need to do other things based on the fact its a tab bar. see one of the hundreds of other questions on it for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This only works if you subclass your own `UIViewController`. Apple's default implementation returns `NO` for all these values except for `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` (obviously). So create a new file, make it a subclass of `UIViewController`, go to its `.m` file and paste this in:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES; //that's enough
}
```

Then use this subclass as your view controller and the rotation will work.

Comment: Sure this doesn't work either `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}` and the funny thing is that when i start the app where the launch image should be seems to be rotated

Comment: That's because the `Info.plist` values mainly apply for the `Default.png` image. Rotation in the app is up to the view controllers' configurations.